# insert image into Mysql database using ionic2

Tags: php, mysql, ionic2

I have trying to upload image from my device camera and insert it into a folder on a server , how can i modify the code below in order to save the captured image into a database table .

```html
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
require_once("db_connect.php");
$target_path = "image/";
if(isset($_FILES['file']))
{
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
{
    $image=basename( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],".jpg"); // used to store the filename in a variable

    //storind the data in your database
  // $query= "INSERT INTO items VALUES ('{$image}')";
    //mysqli_query($con,$query);
echo "success";
} else 
{
echo $target_path;
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: is it required to store the image in the database? if not store only the image url.

Comment: should store the target path into the DB not the tmp path

Comment: If you start with databases, then start simple, with numbers and texts. Try things out, read the manual and tutorials. When you're done that, reconsider storing whole images in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the image to the database it may be better to only store the path of the image in your database. 
I did not test this code, but i think you can accomplish it like this:

```
// This is the folder name where the images are going to be uploaded.
$storeFolder = '/images';  

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $uploads_dir = __DIR__ . $storeFolder;

       $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
       $name = time() . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

       if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name")) {
          //File is uploaded. Show some message if you want. 
       }else {
          //Handle error
       }  
}
```